# numpy multidimensional lookup

Tags: python, numpy, lookup-tables

```
lookup = numpy.array([
    [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
    [["g", "h", "i"], ["j", "k", "l"]],
    [["m", "n", "o"], ["p", "q", "r"]],
    ])
i = numpy.array([
    [[0,0,0], [1,0,2],],
    [[2,0,1], [1,0,2],],
    ])
```

I want to use array *i* to access values in array *lookup*. *i* has the dimensions m x n x 3 (3 because *lookup* is a 3-dimensional array). So I'd like to get an array of the dimensions m x n filled with the values of a[i[m][n]]. So in this case expected:

```
out = [
["a", "i"],
["n", "i"]
]
```

I can manage with for loops in python, but how could I go about this in numpy?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the coordinates from `i` and use them to extract a subset of `lookup`.

```sh
import numpy 

lookup = numpy.array([
    [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]],
    [["g", "h", "i"], ["j", "k", "l"]],
    [["m", "n", "o"], ["p", "q", "r"]],
    ])
i = numpy.array([
    [[0,0,0], [1,0,2],],
    [[2,0,1], [1,0,2],],
    ])
    
x = i[:,:,0]
y = i[:,:,1]
z = i[:,:,2]

out = lookup[x,y,z]
```

##### Output

```sh
[['a' 'i']
 ['n' 'i']]
```